# unable to install paramiko (python2) on RHEL (ootpa 8)

Tags: linux, installation, paramiko, rhel8

Environment:

VM Details:
OS : RHEL 8 - Linux - OOTPA

uname -r
4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.ppc64le

It has both python2.7 and python3.

Problem:

Unable to install paramiko using pip2

When I run this command: "pip2 install paramiko"

I get this ugly error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached paramiko-2.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.4.0.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.4.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (55 lines):
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cffi>=1.4.1
    Using cached cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
  Collecting pycparser
    Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cffi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycparser, cffi
      Running setup.py install for cffi: started
      Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bLbRsK/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bLbRsK/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-WbvfRD/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay/include/python2.7/cffi
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bLbRsK/cffi/
      Complete output (36 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7
      creating build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-ppc64le-2.7/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-ppc64le-2.7
      creating build/temp.linux-ppc64le-2.7/c
      gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mcpu=power8 -mtune=power8 -funwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mcpu=power8 -mtune=power8 -funwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-ppc64le-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
      c/_cffi_backend.c:2:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bLbRsK/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bLbRsK/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-WbvfRD/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay/include/python2.7/cffi Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-1Wt80A/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.4.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I have tried to install all packages possible but the issue is RHEL is pathetic, it has such unique package names that the VM itself gets confused and fails to install them.